# Tkinter problems with grid

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am working on a Tkinter incremental game for Python 2.7.9 (Cookie-Clicker style game) and I am stuck with grids.

I wanted the Tkinter window to have three columns: The first column is for the automatic money generators, the second for the main clicker and the third for upgrades. The top row was an exception: I wanted the top row to have the balance of the player (i.e. how much money they have) on the left, and the MPS (money per second) at the right.

I followed everything the guide over at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm, but none of the code I tried works (all of the widgets are stuck in the one column)!

Here is the code:

```
checklabel1 = Label(master, textvariable=moneytkinter)
checklabel1.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
checklabel1.pack()

mpslabel = Label(master, textvariable=mpstkinter)
mpslabel.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
mpslabel.pack()

clickbutton = Button(master, textvariable=inctkinter, command=collectmoney)
clickbutton.grid(row=1, column=1)
clickbutton.pack()

incbutton1 = Button(master, textvariable=autopricetkinter, command=deduction1)
incbutton1.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
incbutton1.pack()

checklabel2 = Label(master, textvariable=autoclicktkinter)
checklabel2.grid(row=2, sticky=W)
checklabel2.pack()

incbutton2 = Button(master, textvariable=printpricetkinter, command=deduction2)
incbutton2.grid(row=3, sticky=W)
incbutton2.pack()

checklabel3 = Label(master, textvariable=printmoneytkinter)
checklabel3.grid(row=4, sticky=W)
checklabel3.pack()

clickboost1 = Button(master, text="Click Boost (Costs: $2000)", command=clickboost1)
clickboost1.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
clickboost1.pack()

boostbutton1 = Button(master, text="Auto Clicker Boost (Costs: $5000)", command=boostauto1)
boostbutton1.grid(row=2, sticky=E)
boostbutton1.pack()

boostbutton2 = Button(master, text="Money Printer Boost (Costs: $100000) command=boostauto2)
boostbutton2.grid(row=3, sticky=E)
boostbutton2.pack()
```

If you want the full code, here it is: https://github.com/DerpfacePython/Click-Incremental-Game1/blob/master/game.py

P.S. I did check other questions, but none of it really applies to the problem at hand (I used the 'Similar Questions' tab, because I have no idea what to type in to solve the problem).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should specify what you exactly mean by *none of it works* , what are you getting instead , what did you expect to get?

Comment: You can't use `grid()` and `pack()` at the same time.

Comment: @VRage Uh... can you please post an answer? I don't really know what you mean.

Comment: VRage is saying you need to either 1) get rid of all those `pack` commands or 2) get rid of all the `grid` commands. But it's not easy to debug your code fully in its current state. Where are the definitions for all of your `StringVar`s, eg `moneytkinter`, and where are your callback functions? And why do you have multiple definitions for most of your Labels and Buttons? Please change your code so that it's a [MCVE].

Comment: @PM2Ring I've placed a link to the GitHub, which has my full code.

Comment: @VRage: be careful with that advice. You can use them at the same time, as long as you don't use both with widgets that share the same parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like said in the comments, you can't use `grid` and `pack` at the same time (with same parent). So if you need row and columns just use `grid` and delete `pack`. Also specify columns in your `grid`-method.

```
''' Column block 0'''
checklabel1 = Label(master, textvariable=moneytkinter)
checklabel1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3) # columnspan = overlap 3 columns

mpslabel = Label(master, textvariable=mpstkinter)
mpslabel.grid(row=1,  column=0)

clickbutton = Button(master, textvariable=inctkinter, command=collectmoney)
clickbutton.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="WE")

incbutton1 = Button(master, textvariable=autopricetkinter, command=deduction1)
incbutton1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="WE")

''' Column block 1'''
checklabel2 = Label(master, textvariable=autoclicktkinter)
checklabel2.grid(row=1, column=1)

incbutton2 = Button(master, textvariable=printpricetkinter, command=deduction2)
incbutton2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="WE")

''' Column block 2'''
checklabel3 = Label(master, textvariable=printmoneytkinter)
checklabel3.grid(row=1, column=2)

clickboost1 = Button(master, text="Click Boost (Costs: $2000)", command=clickboost1)
clickboost1.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="WE")

boostbutton1 = Button(master, text="Auto Clicker Boost (Costs: $5000)", command=boostauto1)
boostbutton1.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="WE")

boostbutton2 = Button(master, text="Money Printer Boost (Costs: $100000)", command=boostauto2)
boostbutton2.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="WE")
```

Comment: Just asking, what happens if you do use `grid` and `pack` at the same time? Is it like my code, and the `pack` overrides the `grid` - or is that just an exception?

Comment: In your case it overrides the `grid`, because you didnt used `grid` or `pack` seperated. So if you do something like this: `button1.pack()` and `button2.grid()` your GUI wouldn't show up and you don't get any error messages.